# is possible to add a request header whose value is computed with an async invocation?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, async-await

I've tried almost everything without success

Mi intention is to use manifest.json V3. With V2, and XmlHttpRequest (with its lovely 'async:false') there would be no problems

My header modifying code:

```
chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
    removeRuleIds: [MY_CUSTOM_RULE_ID],
    addRules: [
        {
            id: MY_CUSTOM_RULE_ID,
            priority: 1,
            action: {
                type: "modifyHeaders",
                requestHeaders: [
                    {
                        operation: "set",
                        header: "rdp",
                        value: getValue() // implemented by a fetch to some file://...
                    }
                ]
            },
            condition: {
                "resourceTypes": ["main_frame", "sub_frame"]
            },
        }
    ],
});
```

My manifest

```
{
    "name": "RDP header",
    "version": "0.0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "description": "Adds an rdp header",
    "icons": {
        "256": "icon.png"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "declarativeNetRequest"
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
        "http://desktop-hkvv1e5/",
        "file:///*"
    ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "main.js"
    }
}
```

I cannot figure out how to use await here because of the so modern "declarative" style of the new API. It must be a way ¿isn't it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, there's no way by design because this API is *declarative*. You'll have to compute the value before calling updateDynamicRules.

Comment: This comment really helps me because my intention was to load the header for each request (what, thanks to you, I know now its not possible). I can indeed really invoke an async function to load the header, as the @CryptoAlgorithm answer points out, but the loaded value will be computed only once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap your `updateDynamicRules` call in an `async` function, something like:

```js
// Your getValue function might look like...
// populate it with your own async calls to the API
const getValue = async () => {
    return (await (await fetch('some url', {...options})).json())['headerValue'];
    // This is just a really crude example of how it might be done
}

const update = async () => {
    chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
        removeRuleIds: [MY_CUSTOM_RULE_ID],
        addRules: [
            {
                id: MY_CUSTOM_RULE_ID,
                priority: 1,
                action: {
                    type: "modifyHeaders",
                    requestHeaders: [
                        {
                            operation: "set",
                            header: "rdp",
                            value: await getValue() // Use await here
                        }
                    ]
                },
                condition: {
                    "resourceTypes": ["main_frame", "sub_frame"]
                },
            }
        ],
    });
}

// To call the update function, do something like
update().then(() => console.log('Updated!');
```